# How do I get the Catch a Cold achievement?

Tags: toki-tori

In Toki Tori, the Catch a Cold achievement requires me to find ten snowflakes before they melt.

What levels are those snowflakes in, and is there a guide to getting each one of them fast enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The snowflakes are in these Forest Falls levels:

- **Normal**: 1, 6, 11, 12
- **Hard**: 1, 2, 3, 5
- **Bonus**: 2, 3

I've found this helpful [video guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n51ZG-WKkso) for reaching them quickly:

Note that the solution for Hard 1 is incorrect (because it was changed since this guide was uploaded), but the annotations tell you what to do.